# Open Stack Exchange website links in the iOS app with universal links

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, ios-app

It would be nice if the iOS app would support universal links for all Stack Exchange websites so that links are automatically opened in the app.

Comment: You know you can deactivate it with a single tap?